# How to return value in coroutine scope?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is it possible to to return value in `Coroutine Scope` without run blocking?
For now my code in repository looks like this:

```
    suspend fun getWorkItem(workItemId: Int): WorkItemRoom? {
        runBlocking {
            return@runBlocking
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                getWorkItemByIdUseCase.build(workItemId)
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

this is my useCase

```
class GetWorkItemByIdUseCase(private val workItemDao: WorkItemDao) :
    BaseUseCase<Int, WorkItemRoom>() {
    override suspend fun create(id: Int): WorkItemRoom {
        return workItemDao.getWorkItemById(id)
    }

}
```

baseUseCase

```
abstract class BaseUseCase<P, R> {
    protected abstract suspend fun create(params: P): R
    open suspend fun build(params: P): R = create(params)
}
```

Dao

```
@Dao
abstract class WorkItemDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM workitem WHERE id=:id")
    abstract suspend fun getWorkItemById(id: Int): WorkItemRoom
}
```

... but certainly I know it is not a proper solution. How would you achieve this? In `viewmodels' or fragments I can directly use` lifecycleScope`, but what in other cases, where the must is to call useCase directly from method below. Is it efficient to call Dispatchers.Main all the time?

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { }
```

Comment: Frankly speaking, your code inside `getWorkItem()` looks like a result of some random code generator :-P `runBlocking()` inside a suspend function doesn't make sense. `return` immediately at the start of a block doesn't make sense. Using `launch()` if you need to wait for a result doesn't make sense. Why won't you just invoke `getWorkItemByIdUseCase()` directly and don't use any of above?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to use `runBlocking` in a suspend function. (It hardly ever makes sense to use it at all, except as a bridge between coroutines and non-coroutine code in a project that is partially converted to using coroutines but still needs to support legacy code or libraries.)

You should just call the function you need.

```
suspend fun getWorkItem(workItemId: Int): WorkItemRoom? { //may not need nullable return value
    return getWorkItemByIdUseCase.build(workItemId)
}
```

If you need to specify a dispatcher, use `withContext`:

```
suspend fun getWorkItem(workItemId: Int): WorkItemRoom? = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { 
    getWorkItemByIdUseCase.build(workItemId)
}
```

However, if `build` is a suspend function, there's no need to specify a Dispatcher when calling it. Suspend functions are responsible for internally calling their functions on appropriate threads/dispatchers.

If you need a coroutine scope inside a coroutine or suspend function, use the lowercase `coroutineScope` function, which creates a scope that will be automatically cancelled if the coroutine is cancelled. This example doesn't make much sense, because normally you don't need a new scope unless you are running parallel jobs inside it:

```
suspend fun getWorkItem(workItemId: Int): WorkItemRoom? = coroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main) { 
    getWorkItemByIdUseCase.build(workItemId)
}
```

Comment: True, suspend fun getWorkItem(workItemId: Int): WorkItemRoom? = getWorkItemByIdUseCase.build(workItemId) works :) 
I am going into investigation to read more about suspend functions that is so! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass the value from a coroutine to liveData and then use an observer

```
private val observableMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<Type>()
val observableLiveData: LiveData<Type> = observableMutableLiveData
```

and later in a coroutine:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    observableMutableLiveData.postValue(value)
}
```

and then in an activity:

```
viewModel.observableLiveData.observe(this) { Type ->
   Log.i("result", Type)
}
```

Comment: The `CoroutineScope` constructor should generally never be used to call a one-off coroutine on it. There's no reason to create a CoroutineScope that is not going to be managed. Better to use GlobalScope to indicate intent rather that creating a code smell.

Comment: GlobalScope is marked with DelicateCoroutinesApi and while using it, it is very easy to accidentally create memory leaks. I agree with the ```CoroutineScope``` part tho, I would just use a viewModelScope to do the job

Comment: It's equally easy to create memory leaks using `CoroutineScope` as it is with GlobalScope, actually more-so, because you don't get the warning.

Comment: Nice solution, maybe it is also possible to use flow instead livedata.

Comment: It is, do you want me to include the "flow version" too?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever listened about a **lambda**?
It looks like `call: (MyResult) -> Unit`
I use it from time to time like

```
fun someToDo(call: (MyResult) -> Unit) {
    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val result = getFromSomeWere()
        launch(Dispatchers.Main){call(result)}
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't use it like this, but looks interesting.